# Authenticating/Authorising AJAX requests from client browser

Tags: ajax, authentication, browser, request

We have a web service which is available to clients who register with us. We get the username, password and the IP/domain of the client during registration. This webservice can be used by the registered clients in their applications. 
How do we authenticate the client if the webservice call is made through a browser using AJAX request.
We are currently authenticating by using getReferrer (which gives us the client domain). Would like to know if there is a better way to handle this authentication.

Appreciate your help in this regard.

Thanks
Anil K

Answer (score 1):

One way to secure the web service will require the following steps:

- Add functionality on your website from where registered clients can request for an "API Key". This "key" will be a unique random string (preferably a fixed length string).
- The first web service call made by the client should be an authenticate call. In this call the client must pass the "API key" as HTTP header value. On the server end, you should validate if the incoming IP/domain and "API key" are from a registered client or not. This way the client will not have to send "username/password" for authentication.
- If the key and IP/domain matches then you can assume that this web service call is from a valid client. Now on the server-end, generate a "token" (a unique random string) and send that "token" to the client as a "response" to the authenticate web service call.
- This "token" must be sent by the client in each subsequent web service call. You must check if this is a valid "token". "token" should be expired after a specific time duration. For example, if the "token" was not used during the last 15 minutes then it should be expired and the web service client will have to call the authenticate API again.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hello Aziz, 

Thanks for your response. This involves the client authenticating or sending the token each time to access the webservice. 

The call is not being made by the client. The call is being made by the users of the client's application from the users' browser through AJAX call. Is there a way to authenticate the call from the browser without asking the client to send the token everytime.

Thanks
Anil

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, your clients are registered but their clients (which you call users) are not registering with you directly, correct?

Comment: Hi Anil, unless there is some kind of server interaction involved, you will not be able to make the authentication fool proof. So for now, if you plan to stick with client-side, referrer will work fine. But refer can be changed/spoofed easily. To move a step ahead, you can add another authentication factor in addition to referrer, so that you check two items (a pair) instead of one. For example, give each client a unique "API key" that they send to you in each web service call. Now you'll check if both the referrer and API key match then you know that this is coming from a valid client.

Comment: Thanks Aziz. Will try that.

Regards
Anil